# RxJava combineLatest() how to know which observable emitted a value?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have a code

```
Observable.combineLatest(leftObservable, rightObservable, Pair::new)
    .switchMap(pair -> {
        final Department department = pair.first;
        final Person person = pair.second;
        if(/*person has changed*/){
            // do something
        }
        return repository.loadHourlyTable(department , person);
    });
    ...
```

How to know which observable was changed?

Comment: Why do you want to know that? If you want to react to individual Observable changes, have that observable hot and observe it through multiple means. `combineLatest`'s job is to signal when all sources have a latest value and also signal every time any of it changes, providing the latest values across.

Comment: @akarnokd So there is no way to know which observable emitted a value using combineLatest?

Comment: Wrap items into tuples that identify the source in some way and combine those in combineLatest.

Answer (score -1):

This is possibly an error-prone way to apply RxJava.

Say we want to emit librarian-library then court-lawyer, there's no way to avoid some intermediate state.

```
Department + Person    => Pair
Library    + Librarian => library-librarian
Court      + Librarian => court-librarian   // wrong!
Court      + Lawyer    => court-lawyer
```

The solutions to this depend on how your data is given to you. If each Observable is separate and each index of one corresponds to the same index of the other, you should use `zip` instead of `combineLatest`.

Alternatively if you retrieve a department from a Person (or vice-versa) and it is a stream that can change

```
personObservable.switchMap(person -> person.department()
    .map(department -> new Pair<>(person, department))
  .switchMap({ pair -> repository.loadHourlyTable(pair.first , pair.second) });
```